# What is/are the purpose(s) in exporting an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, amd

New to Typescript.  I can see that you can define an interface and use it throughout a Typescript project.  And I can see many blogs and tutorials and documentation describing how you can "export" an interface.  However, I don't understand why you would ever do this.  I can understand of course exporting classes or constants or variables.... but what benefit ever accrues from exporting an interface?  It seems like you can always use it by reference if necessary?

Clearly I am missing a key concept, and any clarity or insight offered is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like you can always use it by reference if necessary?

Global interfaces are accessible everywhere. For making global interfaces, just put the code in a TypeScript file without top level `import` and `export` keywords.

But, like the old fashion global variables, global interfaces suffer from naming conflicts. Exported interfaces solve the issue.

Example:

```
// a.ts
export interface A {}
export default let a: A;

// b.ts
import b, {A as B} from './a'
// Here, the name of A is B
```

Comment: Thanks @Paleo.  This exactly answers my question, and I now understand perfectly why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

### Compilation safety

You would export an interface so that it can be imported into another class, which will implement it. This way you can get the type safety around the interface contract.

Let's say you have an interface `IPerson` (sorry for the cliche!)

```
export interface IPerson {
    getFirstName(): string;
    getLastName(): string;
    getAgeInYears(): number;
}
```

Now you make a concrete implementation of this interface, called `Person`, but without actually referencing the interface:

```
export class Person {
    private _firstName: string;
    private _lastName: string;
    private _ageInYears: number;

    constructor (firstName: string, lastName: string, ageInYears: number) {
        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._lastName = lastName;
        this._ageInYears = ageInYears;
    }

    public getFirstName(): string {
        return this._firstName;
    }

    public getLastName(): string {
        return this._lastName;
    }

    public getAgeInYears(): number{
        return this._ageInYears;
    }
}
```

Your class will function correctly, and will have all the behaviours expected of an `IPerson`, but if you then add another method to the `IPerson` interface (such as `getFirstPetName(): string`), your project will still continue to build (which could lead to unexpected behaviours).

This can be remedied by importing the interface explicitly, and making `Person` implement it, so that way your project will not build unless `Person` meets the contract.

```
import { IPerson } from "./person.i";

export class Person implements IPerson {
    // ...
}
```

---

### Relying on abstractions

By exporting an interface, it can be imported elsewhere and relied on, rather than your program relying on the concrete implementations. (this is the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle))

If you have a function `getPersonFullName` taking in a `Person`:

```
getPersonFullName(person: Person) {
    return person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName();
}
```

This will not be able to be used on other implementations of `IPerson` even if they meet the same contract and requirements (if you made an `IFictionalPerson`, for example).

By importing `IPerson` and relying on that instead, you can be sure that your function will work with any implementation of `IPerson`, rather than the specific `Person` implementation.

```
import { IPerson } from "./person.i";

getPersonFullName(person: IPerson) {
    return person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @James.... I do understand your example.  But if I have a file with the interfaces in it, and I choose to specifically "implement" the interface explicitly (which seems like best programming practice to me), then I don't need to import it as long as it is in a file with no exports, like a .d.ts file I might construct for my project.  I completely get why interfaces are powerful, I just don't get what the purpose is of exporting them.... because they can be used by reference without export/import.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to export it so that you can use it to model some sort of data format so that you get auto complete in your IDE and type checking during compile.

I have done that myself in situations where I don't need a full blown class so I use an Interface to describe how the data object should look so I do less guessing during development. Interfaces are not compiled out into Javascript and are lost. They are only helpful during compile time or in your IDE for development.